How to install Firefox in a RedHat UBI9 ubi-minimal container running on ARM
I have an image based on registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9-minimal running on a MacBook Pro (M1) using Podman. I need to install Firefox and Gecko via the image's Dockerfile, however, the default repositories available to the package manager for this distribution, microdnf, do not appear to include an installable image for either.
The workaround for Gecko is easy in that I can use cURL with ${GECKOARCH} as a passed variable:
RUN curl -fsSL -o /tmp/gecko.tar.gz "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.34.0/geckodriver-v0.34.0-linux${GECKOARCH}.tar.gz" \
&& tar -C /usr/local/bin/ -xzf /tmp/gecko.tar.gz geckodriver \
&& rm -rf /tmp/gecko.tar.gz

Unfortunately, I have been unable to find a released equivalent for Firefox itself. For Linux on x86, I can use https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US, but no equivalent appears to be available for aarch64 unless I use a nightly build, which isn't acceptable for this image's use.
Is there an alternate repository, or a different method? Any ideas about how to address this issue are appreciated.
